# boot complete broadcast processed serially in KITKAT 4.4.2 <ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED><ActivityManagerService.java>

Tags: android, performance, initialization, broadcastreceiver, boot

There seems to be a very important change in the way ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is sent out in the latest android release.
In JB 4.3, the boot complete broadcast was processed in parallel. Where as in KK 4.4.2 its being processed serially.
This is delaying the start of services after boot up.

[KITKAT 4.4.2](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#5189)

[JELLY BEAN 4.3](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#4512)

Because of this change by Google, my service start is being delayed after boot complete.
One can observe that the device gets sluggish and audio for touch doesn't play-out. All of these because the respective services are starting late.

Also, from the logs I see that the first guy to receive ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED after its is sent out, is receiving it after 16-19 seconds, where as on JBP it hardly takes 10 milliseconds for the first guy in the receiver-queue to get it.

Could anyone who is aware of this change explain why this was made.
It would be a great help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As no one is aware of the reason for this change and the effects of it, issue has been reported on Android Issue Tracker. 
Link-https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66341

Hoping to get an answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The change was made by @hackbod, perhaps she can shed light on the reason.

Her checkin note states:

> Finish issue #10779747: Calendar Storage crash observed...
>
> ...while setting up a new user from settings.
>
> We can now delay broadcasts when there are enough background services
> currently starting (still set to 1 for svelte devices, 3 for normal
> devices).
>
> Add new intent flag to not allow receivers to abort broadcasts, which
> I use to fix an issue with the initial BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast not
> actually requesting pss data at the right time -- it can now be sent
> as an ordered broadcast without the ability for the receivers to cancel
> it.

[Checkin diff](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/diff/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java?r2=%2Fframeworks%2Fbase%2Fservices%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fandroid%2Fserver%2Fam%2FActivityManagerService.java%406285a32f74890b761579b4f67afde1b08763fd0a&r1=%2Fframeworks%2Fbase%2Fservices%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fandroid%2Fserver%2Fam%2FActivityManagerService.java%40e56c2c3f059b24c968a3f28f701b6b6cf5883fd9)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify the follow code 
in frameworks\base\services\java\com\android\server\am\ActivityManagerService.java(line 1974 around):

```
private ActivityManagerService() {
......      
     mBgBroadcastQueue = new BroadcastQueue(this, "background", BROADCAST_BG_TIMEOUT, true);
......
}
```

from:

```
mBgBroadcastQueue = new BroadcastQueue(this, "background", BROADCAST_BG_TIMEOUT, true);
```

to:

```
mBgBroadcastQueue = new BroadcastQueue(this, "background", BROADCAST_BG_TIMEOUT, false);
```

Another solution is just set the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED intent to be "FLAG_RECEIVER_NO_ABORT" in finishBooting()，ActivityManagerService.java:

```
final void finishBooting() { 
... 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED, null); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_USER_HANDLE, userId); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_NO_ABORT);
//add FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND to force the intent in foreground
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,I meet this question now.
BOOT_COMPLETED ordered = true,many services running delay for a long time. 
If I remove all the GMS apps,it'll be OK.Because too many GMS apps register the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to be a bug. Beacuse if I write a demo app to receive the BOOT_COMPLETED as above,the incorrect issue will reappear.

I've checked @hackbod's modification.I don't have any idea except for modifying ordered from true to false.
Waiting for @hackbod's reply!